# Is there a simple way to conditionally enable or ignore entire test suites in Rust?

Tags: unit-testing, rust

I’m working on a Rust library that provides access to some hardware devices. There are two device types, 1 and 2, and the functionality for type 2 is a superset of the functionality for type 1.

I want to provide different test suites for different circumstances:

- tests with no connected device (basic sanity checks, e. g. for CI servers)
- tests for the shared functionality (requires a device of type 1 or 2)
- tests for the type 2 exclusive functionality (requires a device of type 2)

I’m using features to represent this behavior:  a default feature `test-no-device` and optional features `test-type-one` and `test-type-two`.  Then I use the `cfg_attr` attribute to ignore the tests based on the selected features:

```
#[test]
#[cfg_attr(not(feature = "test-type-two"), ignore)]
fn test_exclusive() {
    // ...
}

#[test]
#[cfg_attr(not(any(feature = "test-type-two", feature = "test-type-one")), ignore)]
fn test_shared() {
    // ...
}
```

This is rather cumbersome as I have to duplicate this condition for every test and the conditions are hard to read and maintain.

Is there any simpler way to manage the test suites?

I tried to set the `ignore` attribute when declaring the module, but apparently it can only be set for each `test` function. I think I could disable compilation of the excluded tests by using `cfg` on the module, but as the tests should always compile, I would like to avoid that.

Comment: You could try to annotate a complete mod block instead of single functions

Comment: @hellow But this only works if I want to disable compiling, not for ignoring the test cases, right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there a simple way to conditionally enable or ignore entire test suites in Rust?

The *easiest* is to not even compile the tests:

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    #[test]
    fn no_device_needed() {}

    #[cfg(feature = "test1")]
    mod test1 {
        fn device_one_needed() {}
    }

    #[cfg(feature = "test2")]
    mod test2 {
        fn device_two_needed() {}
    }
}
```

> I have to duplicate this condition for every test and the conditions are hard to read and maintain.

1. Can you represent the desired functionality in pure Rust? **yes**
2. Is the existing syntax overly verbose? **yes**

This is a candidate for a macro.

```
macro_rules! device_test {
    (no-device, $name:ident, {$($body:tt)+}) => (
        #[test]
        fn $name() {
            $($body)+
        }
    );
    (device1, $name:ident, {$($body:tt)+}) => (
        #[test]
        #[cfg_attr(not(feature = "test-type-one"), ignore)]
        fn $name() {
            $($body)+
        }
    );
    (device2, $name:ident, {$($body:tt)+}) => (
        #[test]
        #[cfg_attr(not(feature = "test-type-two"), ignore)]
        fn $name() {
            $($body)+
        }
    );
}

device_test!(no-device, one, {
    assert_eq!(2, 1+1)
});

device_test!(device1, two, {
    assert_eq!(3, 1+1)
});
```

> the functionality for type 2 is a superset of the functionality for type 1

Reflect that in your feature definitions to simplify the code:

```
[features]
test1 = []
test2 = ["test1"]
```

If you do this, you shouldn't need to have `any` or `all` in your config attributes.

> a default feature `test-no-device`

This doesn't seem useful; instead use normal tests guarded by the normal test config:

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    #[test]
    fn no_device_needed() {}
}
```

If you follow this, you can remove this case from the macro.

---

I think if you follow both suggestions, you don't even need the macro.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a perfect solution, but i had a similar issue (slow database tests that I didn't want to run as part of my regular unit tests.) My solution was to mark every test in the test suite `[ignore]` and then use `cargo test suite-name -- --include--ignored`:

```rust
// In my_module.rs
#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    #[ignore]
    #[test]
    fn test_one () {
       ...
    }

    #[ignore]
    #[test]
    fn test_two () {
       ...
    }

    ...
}
```

These test compiled by `cargo test` but not run. Then you can specifically run these tests with `cargo test my_module::test -- --include-ignored`.

Its annoying to need to `[ignore]` each test individually but at least it gives you a way to run that test suite specifically without running other ignored tests from other modules.